# Java - Query does not return results

Tags: java, sql

> java.sql.SQLException: Query does not return results

This is the error I get when running my code.

I am making a tic-tac-toe game to run off of a database. I'm making an empty board with this code.

Any ideas of why the database is not being updated??

```
//INSERT SPACE
    String space1 = "INSERT INTO space(row,column,contents) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    String space2 = "INSERT INTO space(row,column,contents) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    String space3 = "INSERT INTO space(row,column,contents) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    String space4 = "INSERT INTO space(row,column,contents) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    String space5 = "INSERT INTO space(row,column,contents) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    String space6 = "INSERT INTO space(row,column,contents) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    String space7 = "INSERT INTO space(row,column,contents) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    String space8 = "INSERT INTO space(row,column,contents) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    String space9 = "INSERT INTO space(row,column,contents) VALUES (?,?,?)";


    /**
     *  Inserts empty space into space 1
     */
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connectDatabase.getConnection().prepareStatement(space1);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2,0);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, "e");

        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        resultSet.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What kind of result you're expecting from an `INSERT` ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()` instead. See the docs [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())

The method `.executeQuery()` is only used for `SELECT` operations, or in general for any queries that *return* something. If, instead, you want to *modify* your database, you must use `.executeUpdate()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                                               ^^^^^^
```

`ExecuteUpdate` is the method to use for non-results-returning DML.